# C# GZipStream compressing data but decompression returns empty stream

Tags: c#, compression, gzip

I have the following code:

```csharp
    public static async Task<string> Compress(string inputString)
    {
        var bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(inputString);
        await using var input = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        await using var output = new MemoryStream();
        await using var stream = new GZipStream(output, CompressionLevel.SmallestSize);

        await input.CopyToAsync(stream);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(output.ToArray());
    }

    public static async Task<string> Decompress(string inputString)
    {
        var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(inputString);

        await using var output = new MemoryStream();
        await using var input = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        await using var stream = new GZipStream(input, CompressionMode.Decompress);

        await stream.CopyToAsync(output);
        await stream.FlushAsync();
        
        return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(output.ToArray());
    }
```

When I try to compress the string 'Hello World', the compressed Base64 encoded string is 'H4sIAAAAAAACCg=='

When I try to decompress the Base64 encoded string 'H4sIAAAAAAACCg==' the method Decompress returns an empty string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `GZipStream` respectively its internal `DeflateStream` is designed to implicitly flush its internal buffer on a call to `Dispose` (see [https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.IO.Compression/src/System/IO/Compression/DeflateZLib/DeflateStream.cs](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/sys/system/IO/compression/DeflateStream.cs)).

For using statements without curly braces, which have been introduced with C# 8.0, the scope is limited by the containing scope. In this case, the containing scope is the method itself, which means that the object goes out of scope when the method finally exits. Therefore, the implicit flush from `stream` to `output` happens after `Convert.ToBase64String(output.ToArray())`.

To avoid this, we can add curly braces to limit the scope (see example below), or by flushing the `stream` explicitly (this is not valid for all .NET versions, see https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/commit/728aa671567d498c1acb6e13cb5cf4f7a883acf7 .

```
public static async Task<string> Compress(string inputString)
{
    var bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(inputString);
    
    await using (var input = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        await using (var output = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await using (var stream = new GZipStream(output, CompressionLevel.SmallestSize))
            {
                await input.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }
        
            return Convert.ToBase64String(output.ToArray());
        }
    }
}

public static async Task<string> Decompress(string inputString)
{
    var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(inputString);

    await using (var output = new MemoryStream())
    {
        await using (var input = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            await using (var stream = new GZipStream(input, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                await stream.CopyToAsync(output);
            }
        }

        return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(output.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are not getting the correct compressed string. `output.ToArray()` is being called before `stream` `GZipStream` is flushed, so the contents of `output` `MemoryStream` would not be the full compressed bytes yet. You need to add `await stream.FlushAsync();` after `await input.CopyToAsync(stream);`.